# How to implement istio authorization using oauth2 and keycloak

Tags: kubernetes, oauth-2.0, keycloak, istio, istio-gateway

I have been trying to implement istio authorization using Oauth2 and keycloak. I have followed few articles related to this [API Authentication: Configure Istio IngressGateway, OAuth2-Proxy and Keycloak](https://medium.com/@senthilrch/api-authentication-using-istio-ingress-gateway-oauth2-proxy-and-keycloak-part-2-of-2-dbb3fb9cd0d0), [Authorization Policy](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/)

**Expected output:** My idea is to implement keycloak authentication where oauth2 used as an external Auth provider in the istio ingress gateway.
when a user try to access my app in `<ingress host>/app` , it should automatically redirect to keycloak login page.

How do i properly redirect the page to keycloak login screen for authentication ?

**problem:**
When i try to access `<ingress host>/app`, the page will take 10 seconds to load and it gives status 403 access denied.
if i remove the authorization policy (*kubectl delete -f authorization-policy.yaml*) within that 10 seconds, it will redirect to the login screen (*keycloak*)

oauth2.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: oauth-proxy
  name: oauth-proxy
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: oauth-proxy
  ports:
  - name: http-oauthproxy
    port: 4180
    nodePort: 31023
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: oauth-proxy
  name: oauth-proxy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "oauth-proxy"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: oauth-proxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: oauth-proxy
        image: "quay.io/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy:v7.2.0"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4180
        args:
          - --http-address=0.0.0.0:4180
          - --upstream=http://test-web-app:3000
          - --set-xauthrequest=true
          - --pass-host-header=true
          - --pass-access-token=true
        env:
          # OIDC Config
          - name: "OAUTH2_PROXY_PROVIDER"
            value: "keycloak-oidc"
          - name: "OAUTH2_PROXY_OIDC_ISSUER_URL"
            value: "http://192.168.1.2:31020/realms/my_login_realm"
          - name: "OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_ID"
            value: "my_nodejs_client"
          - name: "OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET"
            value: "JGEQtkrdIc6kRSkrs89BydnfsEv3VoWO"
          # Cookie Config
          - name: "OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECURE"
            value: "false"
          - name: "OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECRET"
            value: "ZzBkN000Wm0pQkVkKUhzMk5YPntQRUw_ME1oMTZZTy0="
          - name: "OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_DOMAINS"
            value: "*"
          # Proxy config
          - name: "OAUTH2_PROXY_EMAIL_DOMAINS"
            value: "*"
          - name: "OAUTH2_PROXY_WHITELIST_DOMAINS"
            value: "*"
          - name: "OAUTH2_PROXY_HTTP_ADDRESS"
            value: "0.0.0.0:4180"
          - name: "OAUTH2_PROXY_SET_XAUTHREQUEST"
            value: "true"
          - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_PASS_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER
            value: "true"
          - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_SSL_UPSTREAM_INSECURE_SKIP_VERIFY
            value: "true"
          - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_SKIP_PROVIDER_BUTTON
            value: "true"
          - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_SET_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER
            value: "true"
```

keycloak.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  ports:
  - name: http-keycloak
    port: 8080
    nodePort: 31020
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: keycloak
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:17.0.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        args: ["start-dev"]
        env:
        - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN
          value: "admin"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
          value: "admin"
```

istio-operator.yaml

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  meshConfig:
    accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
    extensionProviders:
    - name: "oauth2-proxy"
      envoyExtAuthzHttp:
        service: "oauth-proxy.default.svc.cluster.local"
        port: "4180" # The default port used by oauth2-proxy.
        includeHeadersInCheck: ["authorization", "cookie","x-forwarded-access-token","x-forwarded-user","x-forwarded-email","x-forwarded-proto","proxy-authorization","user-agent","x-forwarded-host","from","x-forwarded-for","accept","x-auth-request-redirect"] # headers sent to the oauth2-proxy in the check request.
        headersToUpstreamOnAllow: ["authorization", "path", "x-auth-request-user", "x-auth-request-email", "x-auth-request-access-token","x-forwarded-access-token"] # headers sent to backend application when request is allowed.
        headersToDownstreamOnDeny: ["content-type", "set-cookie"] # headers sent back to the client when request is denied.
```

gateway.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: test-gateway
  namespace : istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - '*'
```

virtual-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: gateway-vs
spec:
  hosts:
    - '*'
  gateways: 
    - istio-system/test-gateway
  http:
    - match:
      - uri:
          prefix: /oauth2
      route:
      - destination:
          host: oauth-proxy.default.svc.cluster.local
          port:
            number: 4180
    - match:
      - uri:
          prefix: /app
      route:
      - destination:
          host: test-web-app.default.svc.cluster.local
          port:
            number: 3000
```

authorization-policy.yaml

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: example-auth-policy
spec:
  action: CUSTOM
  provider:
    name: "oauth2-proxy"
  rules:
  - to:
    - operation:
        paths: ["/app"]
        notPaths: ["/oauth2/*"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirection issue solved by updating authorization policy

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: example-auth-policy
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  action: CUSTOM
  provider:
    name: "oauth2-proxy"
  rules:
  - to:
    - operation:       
        paths: ["/app"]
        notPaths: ["/oauth2/*"]
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: istio-ingressgateway
```

- Added `istio-system` namespace instead of workload namespace (it was default in my case)
- Forgot to add `matchLabels`.